# issue with Verbatim

Tags: color, verbatim, fancyvrb

I have a `\n` in my code which is not compiling correctly in verbatim environment.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars = \\\{\}]
"A very very \n long title"     \textcolor{red}{A very very long title}
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}
```

I am trying to get `''A very very \n long title''`. And the sentence after it in red color

How to fix this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is a bit unclear but I think you want

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars = !\{\}]
"A very very \n long title"     !textcolor{red}{A very very long title}
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 3):

When using `commandchars` in [`fancyvrb`](//ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb), the resulting characters are executed/processed as (La)TeX characters rather than being set `verbatim`. You've set `\`, `{` and `}` to be treated as such. Therefore, any control sequence (starting with a `\`) will have to be defined.

In your case, `\textcolor` exists (from [`color`](//ctan.org/pkg/color)), but `\n` does not. You can define `\n` to set `\string\n` (output similar to `\n`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyvrb,xcolor}

\newcommand{\n}{\string\n}

\begin{document}

\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars = \\\{\}]
"A very very \n long title"     \textcolor{red}{A very very long title}
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}
```